# Need to disable styling in a certain part of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an A/B website. Mostly for fun. It has two parts. It fetches a page from the internet and shows it in a container (div#page). So I fetch example.com, and change the base and show it in the div. so far so good.

The uppper part is my site's content(div#header). I show the menu, a form(to specify url) and a couple of other things.

The problem is: the css from example.com also applies to the elements of my site. How do I stop this from happening? I want example.com's css to apply only to #page, not #header

Is there a way of doing this? I know I can use a reset helper, but doesn't seem like an optimal solution: having to redefine everything. Plus then my site's css will apply to example.com

Any ideas, or is this undoable?

Comment: are you using an iframe?

Comment: No. I need to be able to interact with the other page via javascript. Is that possible via an iframe?

Comment: yes, I've added an answer indicating how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and isolate all your styles from placing a more specific selector in the front of all your selectors in your .css.

So if had a bunch of style selectors:

```
.main{ ... }
#myContainer { ... }
#menu .menu-item { ... }
p { ... }
```

(or what-ever it might be)

Then put an id on your top-most element in your HTML (eg BODY element), something like 'myPage', then change all your css selectors to this:

```
#myPage .main{ ... }
#myPage #myContainer { ... }
#myPage #menu .menu-item { ... }
#myPage p { ... }
```

Comment: sort of what I was trying to avoid.  I wanted styles to only propogate to after the point where they were declared. The previous elements should not be affected. but can't do that, I suppose

Comment: can you explain this statement further (perhaps with an example): "only propogate to after the point where they were declared"

Comment: I meant if i declare styles on line 89 and there are matching elements on line 80, they should not apply to the elements on line 80

Answer (score 2):

Isolate the `example.com` to an iframe. To interact with the javascript on that page, then follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)